# Redirect in .NET Core OpenID Connect middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, openid-connect, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to handle a scenario when the OpenID Connect server I'm authenticating to returns a particular set of querystrings. When the condition matches, I want to essentially redirect the user to an "Access Denied" page. For whatever reason the commented line below containing the redirect never actually fires. Is there a better/different way to do what I'm after?

Here's how the OpenID Connect middleware is configured in **Startup.cs**:

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options => 
{

    // ...

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("error"))
            {
                context.HandleResponse(); // <-- Fires
                context.Response.Redirect("/AccessDenied"); // <-- Redirect fires but user is not redirected
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Got it working with the following tweaks:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("AccessDenied?error=" + context.Failure.Message);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Have you tried not calling `context.HandleResponse();`?

Comment: Removing context.HandleResponse() has no effect and the user still is not ultimately redirected before the user is taken to the callback path uri.

Comment: I think `HandleResponse` is supposed to be last

Comment: Yes `HandleResponse` should be last.

Answer (score 1):

You should not to call HandleResponse() before redirect, as in this case you "tell" to stop processing request in HTTP Pipeline. Change to this:

```
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("error"))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/AccessDenied"); 
            context.HandleResponse(); 
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick. The user still doesn't get redirected.